# How to read a file both in the driver and executors?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a `properties` file which I want to read both at the Spark driver and executor nodes. I need to read this both before starting the `SparkSession` as well as after the `SparkSession` has been initiated.

I am using `yarn` as the master and `client` as the deploy mode. My project structure is something like:

```
project
|- configs
|  |- properties
|- folder-1
|- folder-2
|- main.py
```

If I provide the absolute path of the file, then executors would not be able to read it. However, if I use the option `--files configs/properties-file` and use `SparkFiles.get()`, then the driver isn't able to read it.

Can someone suggest a unified approach which works for both the drivers and executors?

Comment: why would you want to read different properties file for your worker and executor? and why cant you pass through at spark-submit --conf style?

Comment: There are two properties file in the zipped codebase (python project). I was deciding which property file to use ('qa' or 'prod') in the code itself after looking at the environment variable set up.

Comment: then, you need to determine the enviroment at your driver level right? you cant be a situation whether your driver is in dev but your worker is prod. which a bad deploy pattern

Comment: Yes, I determine the environment at the driver itself. And then I want to read the properties file accordingly. However, it throws issues when the code runs at executors.

Comment: whats the full error ?